# How to get the correct local address URI when hosting IIS site on multiple bindings?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, webforms

I have configured a simple service in IIS with multiple port bindings.
The current channel local address is always the same no matter which port was called.

[image: IIS site bindings]
.

```cs
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class TestService : ITestService
{
  public string Test()
  {
    return OperationContext.Current.Channel.LocalAddress.Uri.Port.ToString();
  }
}
```

Call to `testHost2:7772` -> returns **7772**

Call to `testHost1:7771` -> returns **7772** too

Answer (score 0):

You could use this below code to get the hostname and the port using WCF:

```
var test = OperationContext.Current.Host.BaseAddresses[0].Authority;
```

or

```
Uri uri = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.To ;
```

Comment: `OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.To.Port` returns 7772, `OperationContext.Current.Host.BaseAddresses` contains both addresses but i can't find out which address is called, Its like IIS is redirecting to the first endpoint always @JalpaPanchal

Comment: use this "OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.To" do not add "port".

Comment: How is that any diffrent? `To` returns `URI` object that contains the first binding not the second. No matter what endpoint is called.

Comment: did you try "var test = OperationContext.Current.Host.BaseAddresses[0].Authority;"

Comment: BaseAddresses Contains both bindings, but i don't know how i can identify which one is called `BaseAddresses[0]` or `BaseAddresses[1]`.

Comment: seems wcf not supported multiple binding.